# main() wrapper to start wmain() program to compile it from commandline

Tags: c, program-entry-point, wmain

For example i have a program thats "main" function is defined as wmain.

```
int wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[] ) {
    wchar_t* lpModulePath = NULL;
    wchar_t* lpFunctionName = NULL;
    lpModulePath = argv[1];
    lpFunctionName = argv[2];
}
```

and of course uses wchar_t types. How can i write a function

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

that converts the parameters passed as char to wchar_t and then calls wmain by itself?

Thank you

Comment: can you show some more code on what you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "some more"? A working program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can use `GetCommandLineW()` and `CommandLineToArgvW()`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wchar_t** wargv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    int ret = wmain(argc, wargv);
    LocalFree(wargv);
    return ret;
}
```

On Linux I'm afraid you'd have to allocate the array and convert strings in loop.